# Check multiple files with string

Tags: centos, filesystems, kernel-modules

i.e. for each .csv file,  do the following:

- Check if the file contains the string “HEADER” in the first line. If its missing, do the following:

  1. Display, “ERROR: Missing HEADER record for ”
  2. Rename the file from .csv to .head
  3. Proceed to process the next file

Comment: Ok, what's the question?

Answer (score 3):

```
for f in *.csv; do
  IFS= read -r line < "$f" &&
    case $line in (*HEADER*) continue; esac

  printf >&2 'ERROR: Missing HEADER record for "%s"\n' "$f"
  mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}.head"
done
```

Comment: nice one! A question: Does `--` need in `mv` when we have double quote?

Comment: @Gnouc, yes, it's `mv -- "$file" ...` or `mv "$option_or_file" ...` or `mv -- $file_patterns ...` or `mv $option_and_or_file_patterns ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for _file in *.csv
do
    if ! grep -q 'HEADER' <(head -n 1 -- "$_file")
    then
        echo >&2 "ERROR: Missing HEADER record for $_file"
        # mv -- "$_file" "${_file%.*}.head"
        echo "$_file" "${_file%.*}.head"
    fi
done
```

Using `echo` line to verify if it works right, if everything ok, try `mv` line.